# Верны ли знаки препинания в следующем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении: «Когда такая жара, какие микроорганизмы на той кукурузе на пляже размножаются вообще неизвестно». Правильно ли все с пунктуацией?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант редактирования:

*Когда на пляже такая жара, **то** вообще неизвестно, какие микроорганизмы на той кукурузе размножаются.*

Comment: А когда жара не такая, это разве известно? И какая именно кукуруза — та?

Comment: Включите воображение – и увидите, что было до и после.  Додумайте возможный контекст сами, а здесь напишите вариант правки заданного предложения.  А то – когда, какая…

Comment: При чём воображение? У меня логические претензии к вашей правке: она связывает жару с известностью вместо того, чтобы, как подразумевает автор, связывать жару с размножением микроорганизмов. Кроме того из вашей правки уже не следует, что речь идёт о той кукурузе, которая продаётся на пляже, а не о любой.

Comment: Связывает, говорите? А мы сейчас развяжем, добавим местоимение ТО. А дальше вам точно уж воображения не хватило – о какой еще кукурузе может идти речь? На конкретную кукурузу указывает местоимение (на той кукурузе) – о ней, разумеется, и говорится в контексте.

Comment: «Связывает, говорите? А мы сейчас развяжем, добавим местоимение ТО» — не помогло. Думайте ещё :) «На конкретную кукурузу указывает местоимение (на той кукурузе)» — указывает, говорите? :) Это вы просто мало знаете и не в курсе, что как раз там, где имеют место пляжи и кукуруза, в большом ходу «тот» /«та»/«то»/«те» в роли усилительной частицы, — в русском литературном в этом смысле употребляется «какой(-ая, ое, ие)-нибудь». «Мой в экспедициях всю Сибирь объездил, как тот декабрист!»

Comment: Ладно, вот вам еще вариант, его обсуждайте: Когда такая жара, то какие только микроорганизмы на той кукурузе не размножаются! Вопрос! Риторический!

Comment: Не вопрос! Восклицание! И вполне годное! И если это реплика в общении, где всем всё понятно с полуслова, можно действительно не добавлять к кукурузе «пляжная».

Answer (score 0):

При таком порядке слов пунктуация нормальная — сам порядок нехорош. В частности, он потому нехорош, что, пока не дочитаешь до «вообще неизвестно», кажется, что это восклицательное предложение: «Когда такая жара, какие микроорганизмы на той кукурузе на пляже размножаются!» Устраивать читающему такие розыгрыши не есть хорошо. Но если это художественная проза и предложение должно передавать устную (не без косноязычия) речь, то всё нормально. А если нет, предлагаю вариант (с сохранением разговорной интонации — я её люблю), позволяющий избежать недоразумений: «Когда такая жара, так микроорганизмы на той кукурузе на пляже размножаются вообще неизвестно какие».